# ¿Por qué no me imprime el resultado correcto?

Tags: c

Estoy empezando a programar en C y me encuentro con este problema.
Estoy queriendo hacer un programa que, cuando le indiques el ancho y largo de un rectángulo, este calcule el área y su perímetro, pero no lo logro hacer funcionar. Adjunto el código a ver si es posible que alguien me pueda ayudar.

El problema viene en si cuando asigno los valores del rectángulo. La consola me devuelve esto: [image: Devolución de la consola]

Código en C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Crea tu rectangulo:\n");
    printf("Cual es el largo de tu rectangulo?:\n");
    double largo;
    scanf("%d", &largo);
    printf("Cual es el ancho de tu rectangulo?:\n");
    double ancho;
    scanf("%d", &ancho);
    printf("\nEl largo de tu rectangulo es: %d", largo);
    printf("\nEl ancho de tu rectangulo es: %d", ancho);
    double perimetro = 2.0 * (largo + ancho);
    double area = largo * ancho;
    printf("\nEl primetro de tu rectangulo es: %d", perimetro);
    printf("\nEl area de tu rectangulo es: %d", area);
    return 0;
}
```

Intente también cambiar el `%d` por `%f` y no funcionó.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema radica en la forma como pides el dato:

```c
scanf("%d", &largo);
```

La variable `largo` es de tipo `double` pero en el primer parámetro especificas que `scanf` debe leer un `int`, cuando no debería ser así.

El especificador de formato para leer un dato de tipo `double` es `%lf` (para más información leer [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)). Sin embargo, para imprimir el dato puedes usar simplemente: `%f`.

Código corregido:

```c
int main()
{
     //Se ve más ordenado si declaramos las variables al principio :)
     double ancho, largo, perimetro, area;
     printf("Crea tu rectangulo:\n");
     printf("Cual es el largo de tu rectangulo?:\n");
     scanf("%lf", &largo);
     printf("Cual es el ancho de tu rectangulo?:\n");
     scanf("%lf", &ancho);
     printf("\nEl largo de tu rectangulo es: %f", largo);
     printf("\nEl ancho de tu rectangulo es: %f", ancho);
     perimetro = 2.0 * (largo + ancho);
     area = largo * ancho;
     printf("\nEl primetro de tu rectangulo es: %f", perimetro);
     printf("\nEl area de tu rectangulo es: %f", area);
     return 0;
}
```